# C# What does "%Anytext%" mean?

Tags: c#, azure

I found in some c# code a line that uses a string with % at the front and the back of the string.  I have been searching for what this means and how to read the code and could not file anything.  Here is the line of code:

```
public static async Task ProcessMessage([QueueTrigger("%IndexMessage%")] IndexMessage info)
```

In this case, somehow the "%IndexMessage%" translates to a queue name but I don't know where to find it.  How do I read the portion of the code "%IndexMessage%"?

Comment: It is a string. It probably only has meaning to the coder. Did you check QueueTrigger implementation?

Comment: % is a wildcard in Sql Server. Is that value appended to a SqlCommand without using parameters? This could be a Sql Injection vulnerability.

Comment: This is not SQL.  There must be some way to figure out what the string is.  I have seen %sometext% before in other coding but I can't find any documentation about what that means in c#.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be from an Azure Function (or WebJob, which uses similar formatting).  That is a placeholder variable for the name of the queue, which is stored either in the local.settings.json when developing locally, or as an app setting in the portal.  In the portal, you can find this value in the Function's "Application Settings" tab of the Configuration screen. An example from the MS Azure Functions docs:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns#binding-expressions---app-settings